# $s(n^x)$ is not a perfect square for all $x$

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion, perfect-powers

> Does there exist an $n$ such that $s(n^x)$ is not a perfect square for all positive integers $x$ where $s(m)$ denotes the sum of the digits of a positive integer $m$?

If $n = 5$, for example, then take $x = 8$ to get $5^8 = 390625$, which has digit sum $25 = 5^2$.

If $n = 6$, take $x = 2$ to get $6^2 = 36$, which has digit sum $9 = 3^2$.

If $n = 7$, take $x = 7$ to get $7^7 = 823543$, which has digit sum $25 = 5^2$.

For $n = 19$, take $x = 15$ to get $19^{15} = 15181127029874798299$, which has digit sum $100 = 10^2$.

How can we find such an $n$ or prove that none exists?

Comment: To start with something simpler, is it known whether there exists $n$ with $s(n^x)$ even for all $x$?

Comment: If $1\le n\le 10^6$, at least one of the numbers $n,n^2,n^3,\cdots,n^{3442}$ has a digitsum, which is a perfect square.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *very* handwavy argument that none exists.  There are $9 \cdot 10^{k-1}$ numbers with $k$ digits, of which $\sqrt{10^k}-\sqrt{10^{k-1}}=10^{\frac k2}-10^{\frac{k-1}2}=(\sqrt{10}-1)10^{\frac{k-1}2}$ are squares.  We imagine that the numbers of interest are randomly squares or not, so a $k$ digit number has probability $\frac {\sqrt{10}-1}910^{-\frac{k-1}2}$ of being a square.

$n^m$ has $m \log_{10}n$ digits and the average digit is $4.5$, so the digit sum is about $4.5m\log_{10}n$, which has $\log_{10}(4.5m\log_{10}n)=\log_{10}m+c$ digits for a suitable $c$.  The chance for the digit sum to be square is then $\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}9\cdot 10^{-\frac {\log_{10}m+c}2}=\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}9\cdot10^{-\frac c2}\cdot m^{-\frac 12}$.  The sum of these as $m$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$ diverges, so we expect infinitely many cases where the sum of digits of $n^m$ is a square.

Of course, someone could find a number where there is a recurring pattern to make the sum of digits nonsquare.  The squares $\bmod 9$ are $0,1,4,7$ so if there were a number that you could prove the digit sums of the powers were always something else we would have an answer.  For example, the digit sums of $10^m$ are always $1$.  In this cases $1$ is a square, so this is not a problem.

Comment: Since $n^{2r}$ is a square, the sum of its digits will be 0, 1, 4, or 7 modulo 9, so that approach is not going to work.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Good point.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the sum of the digits will be $0,1,4,7,9 \pmod 9$ or that $n^{2r}\equiv \{0,1,4,7\} \pmod{9}$?

Comment: @snu, every positive integer is congruent, modulo 9, to the sum of its digits.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Now that you point that out it makes a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but the following table shows that there are no counterexamples upto $3\ 686\ 021$. It shows the numbers for which the necessary exponent is larger than for the previous numbers.

```
1   1
2   2
5   8
8   12
19   15
32   22
37   94
47   158
146   160
362   272
812   776
842   1090
7814   1622
64961   2390
65681   2752
258935   3432
545993   3442
1224485   4902
2107598   5016
3686021   6862
```

Since the digitsum grows relatively slowly , I expect (in accordance with Ross's heuristic argument) that the digitsum will eventually be a square for every $n$ , but a proof will probably be out of reach.